# C#, quick generics question

Tags: c#

I have a need to create a quick class with just 2 properties (left and top), I'll then call these in a collection.

Is there a quick way to create the class structure without having to actually create the strongly typed class itself using generics?

Thanks in advance

Better still, does the framwework have a built in type than can just store left, top, right, bottom co-ordinates in integer values?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're avoiding creating a class?  That seems like the most direct and straightforward approach, so it's hard to recommend an alternative without knowing what's wrong with it in your situation.

Comment: Please check my update, I know it would take 2 minutes to do it, point is I want to improve my overall knowledge of .net, and find the best way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`System.Drawing.Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx) (which is a struct, not a class by the way; there's a class in `System.Windows.Shapes` but that's different.) There's no point in creating a new generic type when what you want is already in the framework.

Comment: you get a bunch of freebies too

Comment: Except one problem, will this then mean shipping an additional DLL with the package?

Answer (score 9):

Automatic Properties would help make this quick

```
public class Position<T> where T: struct
{
  public T Top { get; set; }
  public T Left { get; set; }
}
```

Or you might want to check out the Point or Rectangle classes in the System.Drawing namespace.

Comment: Thanks will check out that rectangle class!

Comment: I really don't see any point in doing this. It should be a simple class, with Top/Left/Bottom/Right as integer properties.

Comment: you are assuming the position is always in integer. Depending on what the position is for, floats or decimals are also valid.

Answer (score 2):

What's your reason for doing this? Why not just create the class?

If you really need to defer things, you can create an interface:

```
public interface IMyDeferredClass
{
    int MethodReturningInt(int parameter);
    int IntegerProperty { get; set; }
    int this[int index] { get; }
    event EventHandler SomeEvent;
}
```

You can program to IMyDefferedClass, but you'll eventually need a class to implement that interface:

```
public class MyDeferredClass : IMyDeferredClass
{
    public int MethodReturningInt(int parameter)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public int IntegerProperty
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set {  }
    }

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No sorry. Anonymous classes can only be used in the same method without using some *horible* hack from Jon. (See comments)

Comment: That's not *quite* true... http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx

Comment: @Jon:  That's a great point.  It is rather disgusting but it would work.

Answer (score 1):

in C# 3.0 you would need to use reflection.

*Both of these suggestions can have substantial performance overhead.*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var obj = new { Name = "Matt" };
    var val = DoWork(obj); // val == "Matt"
}

static object DoWork(object input)
{
    /* 
       if you make another anonymous type that matches the structure above
       the compiler will reuse the generated class.  But you have no way to 
       cast between types.
    */
    var inputType = input.GetType();
    var pi = inputType.GetProperty("Name");
    var value = pi.GetValue(input, null);
    return value;
}
```

in C# 4.0 you could use the "dynamic" type

```
static object DoWork(dynamic input)
{
    return input.Name;
}
```

interesting Hack pointed out by [Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx)

```
static object DoWork(object input)
{
    var casted = input.Cast(new { Name = "" });
    return casted.Name;
}

public static class Tools
{
    public static T Cast<T>(this object target, T example)
    {
        return (T)target;
    }
}
```